# Ubuntu 16.04 and old version of MySQL

Tags: 16.04, mysql

I have difficulties installing old version of MySQL (5.5.49 or similar to be exact) to Ubuntu 16.04. Tried using:
`sudo apt-get install mysql-server` - Installs 5.7 
`sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.5` - Not finding anything
How it can be solved for good?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mysql server **5.7** is the updated and current version. Since you did not specify the version in the first command, The latest version will be installed for that matter